# How to query from a table to make a single row for multiple row values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I currently have a data set that has all information row-wise.

For example:

| EmpID | Dept | ItemCode | IssueDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | ELECT | 400001 | 28/02/2020 |
| 10002 | MECH | 400001 | 20/03/2020 |
| 10001 | ELECT | 400001 | 01/03/2021 |
| 10001 | ELECT | 400001 | 05/04/2022 |
| 10002 | MECH | 400001 | 28/04/2021 |
| 10003 | CIVIL | 400001 | 28/02/2022 |

Output needs to be like this:

| EmpID | Dept | ItemCode | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | ELECT | 400001 | 28/02/2020 | 01/03/2021 | 05/04/2022 |
| 10002 | MECH | 400001 | 20/03/2020 | 28/04/2021 |  |
| 10003 | CIVIL | 400001 |  |  | 28/02/2022 |

I want to display the output for the last 3 years' data for employees. I would like to write a query in a generic way that displays the last 3 years' data.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

it is called pivot, but as i don't have a 2012 sql server i don't know if pivoz was already there.

so you can use at least the classical way

> ```
> CREATE TABLE items (
>   "EmpID" INTEGER,
>   "Dept" VARCHAR(5),
>   "ItemCode" INTEGER,
>   "IssueDate"  VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO items
>   ("EmpID", "Dept", "ItemCode", "IssueDate")
> VALUES
>   ('10001', 'ELECT', '400001', '28/02/2020'),
>   ('10002', 'MECH', '400001', '20/03/2020'),
>   ('10001', 'ELECT', '400001', '01/03/2021'),
>   ('10001', 'ELECT', '400001', '05/04/2022'),
>   ('10002', 'MECH', '400001', '28/04/2021'),
>   ('10003', 'CIVIL', '400001', '28/02/2022');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> "EmpID", "Dept", "ItemCode"
> , MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(convert(DATE,"IssueDate", 103)) = 2020 THEN "IssueDate" ELSE NULL END) '2020'
> , MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(convert(DATE,"IssueDate", 103)) = 2021 THEN "IssueDate" ELSE NULL END) '2021'
> , MAX(CASE WHEN YEAR(convert(DATE,"IssueDate", 103)) = 2022 THEN "IssueDate" ELSE NULL END) '20212'
> FROM [items]
> GROUP BY "EmpID", "Dept", "ItemCode"
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> EmpID | Dept  | ItemCode | 2020       | 2021       | 20212     
> ----: | :---- | -------: | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
> 10001 | ELECT |   400001 | 28/02/2020 | 01/03/2021 | 05/04/2022
> 10002 | MECH  |   400001 | 20/03/2020 | 28/04/2021 | null      
> 10003 | CIVIL |   400001 | null       | null       | 28/02/2022
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=6bb434cffcdaf65f845565bb3a9a4e23)*